# Nginx and OpenVPN - controlling access to wordpress configuration files

Tags: nginx, openvpn

I'm coming with a question and struggling because I already made setup LEMP + CSF FireWall + Nginx WordPress block + OpenVPN.

So - I have a problem with blocking access to `wp-login.php` file and `/wp-admin` directory at the server.

Already I made successful blocking for anybody there, but I can't make access for connections from VPN tunneling.

Legend:

- IP: 1.1.1.1 - server IP
- IP: 10.8.0.2 - IP what I've got at VPN connection

It's my location blocking block at nginx:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
  allow 1.1.1.1;
  deny all;
}
```

It's my OpenVPN conf file:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

I tried to allow connections for 10.8.0.0/24 and for server IP... and still, I'm getting `error 403` when I'm trying to get there through VPN.

## Edit

I tried to add redirection to VPN `push "redirect-gateway def1"` and in location blocks, I changed from `1.1.1.1` to `10.8.0.0/24` and still nothing (even with 1.1.1.1 don't work).

## Edit 2

I changed assigned IP from VPN to the client 16.8.*.* (/24) address. I can't access to file (wp-*) when I'm giving in block `allow 1.1.1.1; allow 16.8.0.0/24; deny all`.
It's training VPS so I can struggle more with it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What could be happening is that you are trying to access your site using the public IP of your VPN but not the private, seems that you already tried this:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
  allow 1.1.1.1;
  allow 10.80.0.0/24;
  deny all;
}
```

But now try to check what is current IP doing the request, give a try to this:

```
location /myip {
    default_type text/plain;
    return 200 "$remote_addr\n";
}
```

And then query `yoursite/myip` it should print the IP you are using to access and the one probably you want to only allow. (in case is a public IP probably the IP will match the one printed here https://myip.country/ip)

Comment: It give my stationary net IP like it wouldn't be masked through VPN.
BUT! When I'm giving allow for my stationary net IP to that wp-login and deny for all - tu dum.... I GOT BLOCK

Comment: @TheTanadu have you tested without the allow/deny location just to verify the site is working (not blocking you)?

Comment: yup - I tested that with commented location wp-login/wp-admin

Comment: @TheTanadu check the nginx logs probably there you could see the remote IP that is being blocked.

Comment: access.log
     GET - from server IP - so it's fine, because server asking for data to show me
     POST - from stationary IP (not through VPN)
error.log have nothing

Comment: You know thats not your publicly routable IP address, right?  `IP address is in private non-routable range.
Private IP Address Ranges

Address ranges below are reserved by IANA for private intranets, and not routable to the Internet.
For additional information, see RFC 1918.
10.0.0.0 ~ 10.255.255.255 (10.0.0.0/8 prefix)`

Comment: ohhh! Thanks totally forgot that are in networking IANA etc :)

Comment: Eh - Even when I changed assigned IP from VPN to 16.8.*.* (/24) I can't access to file when I'm giving in block `allow 1.1.1.1; allow 16.8.0.0/24; deny all`
It's training VPS so I can struggle more with it :D